# JSLint: I can't appease it on whitespace in a "var" statement

Tags: jslint

I use JSLint and have a huge library of code that is 100% JSLint clean. As of 1.20.2011, JSLint reports errors whitespacing errors on every var statement. Take, for example, this (now hollowed out) function:

```
var dateStrFromTimestamp;
dateStrFromTimestamp = function (t) {
    "use strict";
    var a, d;
    d = new Date(t * 1000);
    a = [];
};
```

JSLint reports:

```
Problem at line 1 character 5: Expected 'dateStrFromTimestamp' at column 3, not column 5.

    var dateStrFromTimestamp;

Problem at line 4 character 7: Expected 'a' at column 5, not column 7.

    var a, d;
```

How am I supposed to write my code? If I follow the recommendation, I'd have to remove the whitespace after the keyword "var" -- but that can't be. So, is the current version of JSLint buggy? Or am I currently blind to something obvious?

Comment: I'm getting similar issues some of the time today; I suspect it's a bug in this version.  It might be worth emailing Crockford and see if he's aware of it.  Does he publish release notes of what he's updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [he's fixed it](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/jslint_com/message/1773).  I continued getting the problem, then did a Shift+refresh to clear his JS file from my cache, and that seemed to fix it I think.

Comment: Yes, that was my post to the Yahoo group :-)

Comment: So it was!  If I'd looked more closely I'd have spotted that :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you mixed tabs ans spaces, and JSLint supposes that a tab is the equivalent of 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there are no tabs in the code example above. (Aside: my actual code does use tabs, but at the beginning of a line, I never mix tabs and spaces.)